# Using iFrame for SPA?

Tags: single-page-application

Our company is redesigning a web service as an SPA. I designed the rough version of frontend using jquery+css+html.  but one of my features is the Tabs interface. It can have up to 8  tabs and it  seemed to slow down the whole web app. Each tab contains a table with sth like 100+ rows with the exception of few  tabs that has a bit more complex ui. 
Now, we have this another company that's been assigned to complete the service with the backend modifications and apply the new ui. This company insists on using iframes to make it easier for multiple developers to work to together at the same time and also improve performance.
I honestly think this makes little sense especially considering the DOM structure is hardly complex nor long for each tab. But the truth is iframe is something i do not like for no apparent reason. So i was wondering if people can advise on why not to use it or even, why i should go along with it

Comment: IMO, you'd better to use a framework (ReactJS, Angular, Ember...) for SPA development. IFrames will make any code communications in / out painful. I guess you are using 'card view' to switch from tab to tab which make your app slow down. if it's the case, maybe try to unload the not visible content from the DOM and inject it back when the tab becomes visible again.

Answer (score 5):

This is a question that is still relevant, so I'll throw in an answer 4 years too late. SPA's can quickly become monolithic, especially for enterprise apps, with slow build times, poor developer experience, framework lock-in and increasing difficulty to coordinate frequent stable releases. This is a more-or-less acknowledged problem, to which the solution goes under the banner micro front ends.

Here's a [thoughtful article on Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html), on micro front ends. You'll note that Iframes are the 2nd "best" solution for creating a shell for your micro front ends, despite the fact that no one wants to use them because they're old fashioned and not cool. They permit a good degree of isolation between frames (separate documents, separate scopes). They're simple and well understood. IFrames descend from framesets, released with Netscape 2 round 1996. Web purists were horrified, but they straight away permitted content panes to scroll independently of the navigation, giving us the left-hand navigation panel that's with us still. So there you have it, frames are a permanently unfashionable but robust and useful solution.

Comment: I would just like to point out a few disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a bad idea to use iframes for this purpose. 
iframe is slow, and pass events and info between the main frame to the iframe is not so easy.

The answer for this is very simple, use **web-components**.

This is solution for multiple developers to work together at the same time.Each developer works on single or multiple web-component, and also make development faster when you can reuse and share components.

If you load the components and render them in the right time you can gain really good performance, better then iframe.

---

Now to your problem, you can do any tab as a component and only when the user move to this tab render it. Thus you dont have to render all the tabs but only one.

Take a look at [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) - a library that is a sugar syntax for web-component.

You can also look at the other frameworks angular,react...

Comment: Yeah this is what im thinking as well. Iv been making a react version of this service and man i gotta say react rocks. I just needed to know if iframe is a legit idea since they argued so strongly for it

Comment: 7 years later, polymer's completely forgotten, web components are still the future, and I just implemented another iframe for loose coupling between spa's.

Answer (score 1):

Iframes can be the best and fastest answer to a micro frontend management.
They have excellent isolation of both style and resources. They allow for independent deployment and simplify splitting layouts.

[This](https://github.com/Alessandroinfo/iframe-micro-frontend) is also a repository that implement Micro Frontend with iframes.

But would just like to point out a few disadvantages.

1. URLs are not synchronized. Difficulty managing routing.
2. iFrames are very heavy.  For each, the browser needs to perform operations that require resources.
3. The UI is not the same and out of sync.  Imagine you need to center a component where the total width is divided between two frames.
4. You have to configure who can use your module into iframes that aren't on the same origin. Security risks.

The choice it's only about what's the best fit for your needs.