# How to load a custom element in another Angular application(single page app)?

Tags: angular, custom-element, micro-frontend

My index.html file of my shell app has a custom `element called overview-cards-element` which I have given in a script tag.
http://localhost:8082/mfe1.js  (It is the compiled js file).

I'm unable to view the custom element on the browser when I serve my shell app(ng serve). I can only see the header and footer from the shell app.
[the header and footer from shell app (footer not shown in image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re0qT.png)
On the other hand I can see the custom element on the browser when I run it from a static index.html file.
[custom element from static index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3TnZ.png)

How can you load a custom element(micro front app) in another single page angular application(called shell app here)? I'm a newbie in the field of custom elements. The intent is to have many micro front ends loaded on a single page angular application. I know webpack module federation is a way but would like to know the other ways to load multiple mfes onto a single page angular application.
Thank You In Advance

I have created a custom element, overview-cards-element following
https://medium.com/swlh/build-micro-frontends-using-angular-elements-the-beginners-guide-75ffeae61b58
and the github
https://github.com/funOfheuristic/micro-fe

Below is the code of the
[app.component.js.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNTT5.png)

This is the code from the single page angular application-
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI7qQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Webpack Module Federation, another approach is using IFrames. However, it's important to pay attention to the disadvantages of IFrames listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75639413/18985812), including security risks. It's also difficult to determine what advantages you have over Module Federation.

If you do decide to use Module Federation, [here](https://www.darklimeteam.com/articles/blog/module-federation-shared-redux) is an article about using Vue custom elements in an Angular app.

Comment: @avariant , you ve found a solution ?